# Unable to resolve $(release.environmentId) in azure devops YAML pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, yaml

$(release.environmentId) is available in classic pipeline.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=batch

But seems like it is unavailabl in YAML pipeline?

Already searched google and SO but couldn't find anything. Please let me know what variables can be used to create this combination.

Comment: Hi @NaveenLuhach, the variable $(release.environmentId) is ONLY available in `classic release` pipeline, it's predefined variable, and it stands for release run environment id. It cannot be combined by other variables. I added the details below. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> But seems like it is unavailabl in YAML pipeline?

Yes, the variable `$(release.environmentId)` is ONLY available in classic pipeline, not exist in yaml/build pipeline.
[image]

> Please let me know what variables can be used to create this combination.

The variable is default predefined variable in classic release, it's release run environment id which you can get from release url for each stage. It's not supported to use other variables to create it in yaml(build) pipeline.

[image]